# New Rails install: ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError FATAL: role does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, postgresql

New to Rails and trying to get a local development environment up and running of a site that's been cloned off of git.

When I start postgres and type 'rails s' in terminal under my project to start the server, I get hit with the following:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2017-01-08 20:43:24] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-01-08 20:43:24] INFO  ruby 2.2.6 (2016-11-15) [i386-mingw32]
[2017-01-08 20:43:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1036 port=3000




Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-01-08 20:43:29 -0500
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-01-08 20:43:29 -0500

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
):
```

If I try and run

```
rake db:create
```

I receive

```
FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:661:in `rescue in
.....
```

Basically the same with rake db:migrate as well. All migrations of the site are in \Sites\sitename\sitename\db\migrate

If I try and create the user

```
psql -U username
```

I'm immediately returned

```
psql: FATAL:  role "username" does not exist
```

I've been wracking my head on this all afternoon.

I'm on a Windows box. Any ideas?

Comment: This depends on how your psql database is setup. Can you remove the `username` and `password` specification from `database.yml` and make it work? If not, do you know what the username and password of your database _should_ be?

Comment: Its probably a permission issue. I would recommend using Docker or some sort of virtual machine host to run some flavor of linux and use that to learn rails. You're going to have far less headaches and actually be able to follow along with tutorials that assume you are using Bash and a real operating system.

Comment: Removed username and password from the 'development' profile under database.yml. There is also a username and password under the 'production' section on the same file, although they're configured quite differently.

ex:
'development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password:'

vs

production:
  <<: *default
  database: appname_production
  username: appusername
  password: <%= ENV['APPNAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>


Not sure what the db was created with other than he originally built it in OSX.

Comment: I plan on getting a linux environment up and running, but tonight's changes are just for some basic front end html/css changes that I'd like to view locally before pushing to git.

Comment: I solve it by running rake db:create && rake db:migrate

Answer (score 16):

Firstly you have to set up your database and create **super user** in psql. Go to psql:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Then you can create user with a password. For example:

```
create user username with password '12345678';
```

Rails will manage database with help of this user. So we have to create a super user too:

```
alter user username with superuser;
```

After you had created a superuser, you can quit from psql. The same data must be in your /**config/database.yml** file:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: database_name
  username: username
  password: '12345678'
```

In the your application repositroy create a database with help of rake:

```
rake db:create
```

Comment: like! .....................

Answer (score 3):

Please update your `database.yml` likewise.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: 'some_name'
  username: 'postgres'
  password: 'postgres'
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

**Postgresql** while installation comes with default `role: 'postgres'` with `Password: 'postgres'`. If you don't want to use it you can create a role and grant them all rights.

```
CREATE ROLE new_user WITH CREATEDB CREATEROLE SUPERUSER;
```

Then update your `database.yml` with the newly created role.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
    <<: *default
  database: 'some_name' #database name
  username: 'postgres' #postgres username
  password: 'postgres' #postgres password
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

rake db:create #to create the db in postgres
rake db:migrate #to run migration(if any) in db/migrate folder
rake db:seed #to run seed file in db/seed.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Login with your pc password  $ sudo su - postgres
2. Then create user $createuser -s -r "YourUsername"
3. $logout
   4.$rails db:create
   5.run the server $ rails s